# TextView doesnot display. But every thing works fine when shown in logcat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I am trying to display the output in text view. But unable to display it . I dont know y it is not displayed in my program
     package com.iiitb.nikhil.sindhu;

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader; 
 import java.io.DataInput;
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.TextView;
  import java.util.*;
 import android.util.*;
   public class LinuxShellCommandAndroidProgramActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView tv;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     tv=new TextView(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream is=new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());

        //os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("/system/bin/chmod 600 /data/data/newfile\n");
        os.writeBytes("cd /data/data/dalvik-cache/\n");
        os.writeBytes("/system/bin/ls -l  /data/dalvik-cache\n");
        String output=new String();

        tv.setText("hii \n");
        //setContentView(tv);
        String temp = new String();
           while((output=is.readLine())!=null)
           {
              Log.i("Check ",output);
              tv.append(output);
           }

            setContentView(tv);
            os.flush();
       } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
     }


   }
 }
```

Comment: first check file is exist in the location ,if if not exist than throws exception and before executing tv.setText("hii \n");
 statement...

Answer (score 1):

set the LayoutParameter on Textview, or just take a layout in your main.xml file and add textview in that layout by `layout.addView(textview);`

**EDITED**

take `tv=new TextView(this);` after calling superClass
like this

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv=new TextView(this);
```

Comment: if you don't mention params it will assume match_parent, so i think that is not the problem.

Comment: You might be right, but can you provide additional proof to that? Just skipped through the `View` and `TextView` code, as well as their doc. Didn't see this stated anywhere *(when creating the view from code)*.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View) , check this out.

Comment: Right, activity. Seen this before and forgot it, had just this vague feeling I'm missing something. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

You must change to that

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);  

....
```

and open res/layout/main.xml 
insert this code betweean linerlayout tags,

```
<TextView android:text="Text box" android:layout_width="60dp" android:id="@+id/tv" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put textview by this method

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");

    ll.addView(tv);
    this.setContentView(sv);
```